# How to reconcile cheek slaps in Matthew 5:39 and John 18:23?

Tags: john, matthew, contradiction

> Matthew 5:39 But I tell you, do not resist an evil person. If anyone slaps you on the right cheek, turn to them the other cheek also.
>
> John 18:23 “If I said something wrong,” Jesus replied, “testify as to what is wrong. But if I spoke the truth, why did you strike me?”

But I tell you, do not resist an evil person.

Comment: Turning one's head, and being silent, are two completely different things.

Comment: It's one thing for someone to slap an equal without just cause, and best to be ignored by proferring the other cheek. It's quite another for a religious ruler, who has convened a Court, to request an Officer of that Court to strike a defendant during a judicial process of questioning. You have not explained why there is a need to 'reconcile' anything. That _should_ have been part of your question.

Comment: I agree with @NigelJ.  There is a huge difference between an everyday tort (civil wrong that causes loss or harm, metaphorical cheek slap) and the abuse of the process of jurisprudence in court.

Answer (score 3):

V38 that precedes Matt. 5:39 has:

> “You have heard that it was said, ‘An eye for an eye and a tooth for a tooth.’ (Matt. 5:38, ESV)

Thus, the context of Matt. 5:39 is retaliation or vengeance.  In John 28:23 Jesus is not retaliating. He is arguing his case.  He is also getting the officer to think about his action.